# CentOS 5 - HTML5 video issues on Google Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, mime-types, mp4, webm

I am trying to reproduce a HTML5 video embedded on my Wordpress site with this code:

```
<video poster="http://www.majestichotelgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Secuencia-foto-Paris-Barcelona.jpg" controls="controls" muted="muted" preload="auto" loop="true" autoplay="true">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.majestichotelgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Secuencia-Barcelona-Paris-no-audio1.mp4">
    <source type="video/webm" src="http://www.majestichotelgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Secuencia-Barcelona-Paris-no-audio1.webm">
    <object width="1900" height="1060" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.majestichotelgroup.com/wp-content/themes/jupiter/js/flashmediaelement.swf">    <param name="movie" value="http://www.majestichotelgroup.com/wp-content/themes/jupiter/js/flashmediaelement.swf"><param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=http://www.majestichotelgroup.com/wp-  content/uploads/2014/03/Secuencia-Barcelona-Paris-no-audio1.mp4"><img src="http://www.majestichotelgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Secuencia-foto-Paris- Barcelona.jpg" title="No video playback capabilities">
    </object>
</video>
```

Note: website is not currently online, you would need to change your host to access to it (213.27.146.189 www.majestichotelgroup.com)

Video worked fine on IE, Mozilla and Chrome but suddenly video stopped to reproduce on Chrome and Firefox. I already added mime-types to .htaccess but issue is still there.

On IE9 Mp4 video is reproduced fine.
On Firefox and Chrome webm file should reproduce but I receive these messages:
Firefox: no video with supported format and MIME type found
Chrome: GET VIDEO.mp4 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE 
        GET VIDEO.webm net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I think it is related with my CentOS 5.10 server configuration.

Could anyone help me with this? I am starting to run out of ideas.

Thanks a lot,
Enrique